# Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, saxon, xliff

I'm using saxon to transfor a batch of XLIFF files by means of a stylesheet. I am getting a few "Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported" messages.

I would assume all these errors are written to a log file, but I can't find it. Any hints?

Thank you.

Cheers, Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do anything to change it, Saxon reports errors to the standard ErrorListener, which writes messages to System.err. If you're running from the command line that goes to the console; if you're running a GUI application it might well disappear into thin air. The easiest way to redirect the messages to somewhere else is to set an ErrorListener on the Transformer / XsltTransformer object.